# Select part of a string

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm looking to select the first word in a nvarchar cell. For example the text fields would read as :

```
Marcus Jones Contractors 
Pertues Smiths Blacksmiths
```

I want to extract only the first world in each row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used the following method:

1. Check if the column is NULL, and use `CharIndex` to see if it contains at least one space - if it is null or there is no space, return the whole value.
2. If there is a space, select a substring of the column from position 0 to where the first space occurs.

Here is the example script:

```
DECLARE @t TABLE (
  data NVARCHAR(max))

INSERT INTO @t
SELECT 'Marcus Jones Contractors'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'Pertues Smiths Blacksmiths'
UNION ALL
SELECT 'SomeOtherValue'

SELECT CASE
         WHEN data IS NULL
               OR Charindex(' ', data) = 0 THEN data
         ELSE Substring(data, 0, Charindex(' ', data))
       END
FROM   @t
```

(To use with your own data, just take the select statement, swap out all occurences of the column name `data` with your column name, and replace `@t` with your table name).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @Foo, 1)
 WHEN 0 THEN @Foo -- empty or single word
 ELSE SUBSTRING(@Foo, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @Foo, 1) - 1) -- multi-word
END
```

You could perhaps use this in a UDF:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[FirstWord] (@value varchar(max))
RETURNS varchar(max)
AS
BEGIN
RETURN CASE CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1)
    WHEN 0 THEN @value
    ELSE SUBSTRING(@value, 1, CHARINDEX(' ', @value, 1) - 1) END
END

GO -- test:
SELECT dbo.FirstWord(NULL)
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('')
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('abc')
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('abc def')
SELECT dbo.FirstWord('abc def ghi')
```

**Or**

```
DECLARE @test NVARCHAR(255)
SET @test = 'First Second'

SELECT SUBSTRING(@test,1,(CHARINDEX(' ',@test + ' ')-1))
```

This would return the result "First"